# Eclipse shows "failed to create drawable" on starting an Android emulator

Tags: eclipse, android-emulator

I just updated my ADT version from 15 to 20 and on launching any of my emulators from the AVD Manager, Eclipse is showing "failed to create drawable". Could you please tell me the reason for this and what should I do in order to resolve this?

Thank you.

Comment: restart your editor and create new emulator then launch app if you got any change then reply me

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I deleted my emulator, restarted Eclipse and created a new emulator but still while launching the emulator it is showing "failed to create drawable". I even restarted my system but it didn't work.

Comment: The "Starting Android Emulator" dialog is showing me this: Starting emulator for AVD 'my_avd'
failed to create drawable
failed to create drawable

Comment: The "Error Log" tab is not showing me anything. When I launch the emulator from the AVD Manager the "Starting Android Emulator" dialog is showing me "failed to create drawable". Usually, it doesn't show any errors, right? It just launches the selected avd.

Comment: I tried it but its still not working. Its still showing me "failed to create drawable" while launching the emulator.

Comment: now once check your sdk is there any missing ? sdk manager > check that is there any "Not Install " . may be that effect over here.

Comment: i know you are very tired by this problem . but something we must have to face.